# InvokeDynamic - how to acces arguments in bootstrap method?

Tags: java, jvm, java-7, bootstrapping, invokedynamic

I am trying to implement "duck typing" with `invokedynamic` in JVM7. I created two different classes, both of them have the method `greet()` which returns `String`. I randomly select between one of them, store the instance on the stack and call `invokedynamic` (using ASM).

I wonder if I can access arguments in bootstrap method. Because I cannot return appropriate `CallSite` with `target` without knowing which object is on the stack and which of the `greet()` methods should be returned.

If my approach is wrong, what is the correct approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer myself.

1. Bind `CallSite` with your own static method (for example `lookup(CallSite cs, Object[] args)`
2. The `args[0]` is the receiver, the rest of them are arguments. Do whatever you wish in the lookup method.

If you are interested in Inline Caching (I was), have a look at these two links:

- [JSR 292 Cookbook presenteation](http://i.cmpnet.com/ddj/images/mediacenter/jvmlanguagesummit/2011_Forax_JSR-292_Cookbook.pdf)
- [JSR 292 - Cascaded inlining Cache Source Code](http://code.google.com/p/jsr292-cookbook/source/browse/trunk/inlining-cache/src/jsr292/cookbook/icache/RT.java)

Comment: This is not really helpful... Do you box the callee and arguments in an array before the `invokedynamic` call?

Comment: Would be nice if you could still tell more about your solution.